# Show more, less list with + - buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show 5 list items first with appending some `...`, then when I click on `+` button, we display all the list, afterthat when I click on `-`, I undo the hidden items.

I need to display just the `+` first without the `-`, and once the list is displayed, the `+` become `-` to hide them again.

Here is my try:

https://jsfiddle.net/mpgt3znj/1/

Thanks

Comment: you are probably looking for something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6FzSb/ apply the same principles you will thrive.

Comment: Not exactly that one, but thanks

Comment: he..he.. =D It's pretty close. It's better for you to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to your problem, it's a little different from the good link that Lakshan offered.

It uses CSS to hide list items over a given value (using the pseudo class `:nth-child(n+6)`, which matches the sixth and greater instance). The code below only does this when the list `ul` element has the `.expanded` or `.collapsed` class.

A short bit of jquery then toggles the `.expanded` and `.collapsed` classes for a `ul` list. A click on the toggle `div` then searches up the DOM tree to the nearest `ul` before flipping it's collapsed/expanded state.

Hope this helps

---

## Solution

```js
// Add click event to all list togggles
$(".list-toggle").click(function() {

  // Move up DOM tree to nearest list
  // Toggle collapsed and expanded classes
  $(this).closest("ul").toggleClass("collapsed").toggleClass("expanded");

});
```

```css
ul.collapsed > li:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}

ul.collapsed > .list-toggle > span.collapse, ul.expanded > .list-toggle > span.expand {
  display: none;
}

.list-toggle {
  width: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.expanded > .list-toggle {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>This list starts with the 'collapsed' class</p>

<ul class="collapsed">

  <li>Point one</li>
  <li>Point two</li>
  <li>Point three</li>
  <li>Point four</li>
  <li>Point five</li>
  <li>Point six</li>
  <li>Point seven</li>
  
  <div class='list-toggle'>
    <span class="expand">+</span>
    <span class="collapse">-</span>
  </div>

</ul>


<p>This list starts with the 'expanded' class</p>

<ul class="expanded">

  <li>Point one</li>
  <li>Point two</li>
  <li>Point three</li>
  <li>Point four</li>
  <li>Point five</li>
  <li>Point six</li>
  <li>Point seven</li>

  <div class='list-toggle'>
    <span class="expand">+</span>
    <span class="collapse">-</span>
  </div>

</ul>
```